# A better way to create a dictionary out of two lists with duplicated values in one

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
a = ["A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "A"]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I want to have a dictionary like the one below:

```
d = {"A":[1, 6], "B":[2, 3], "C":[4], "D":[5]}
```

Right now I am doing something like this:

```
d = {i:[] for i in set(a)}

for c in zip(a, b):
    d[c[0]].append(c[1])
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @wim Yes, actually that is what I need. I made a mistake in my question. It is fixed now.

Comment: Based on your update to the question i think what you have written is pretty clean, i have posted answers before the full question update but honestly my solution with default dict still doesnt really better this since you already know all the keys in advance.

Comment: What you have is fine (existing answers are _worse_ than what you have). Only thing I'd change is emove the redundant `set` call, and perhaps use unpacking in for-loop, i.e. use `for k,v in zip(a, b):` - but these are extremely minor details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dict.setdefault` method to initialize each key as a list and then append the current value to it while you iterate:

```
d = {}
for k, v in zip(a, b):
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

With the sample input, `d` would become:

```
{'A': [1, 6], 'B': [2, 3], 'C': [4], 'D': [5]}
```

Comment: I like your approach! Thanks!

Comment: I was waiting to see if there are anymore responses. I selected your answer as the accepted one. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Running your code, didnt produce the output what you wanted. The below is a bit more verbose but makes it easy to see what the code is doing.

```py
a = ["A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "A"]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
c = {}

for a, b in zip(a, b):
    if a in c:
        if isinstance(a, list):
            c[a].append(b)
        else:
            c[a] = [c[a], b]
    else:
        c[a] = b

print(c)
```

**OUTPUT**

`{'A': [1, 6], 'B': [2, 3], 'C': 4, 'D': 5}`

An alternative less verbose mode would be to use a default dict with list as the type, you can then append all the items to it. this will mean even single items will be in a list. to me its much cleaner as you will know the data type of each item in the list. However if you really do want to have single items not in a list you can clean it up with a dict comprehension

```py
from collections import defaultdict
a = ["A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "A"]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
c = defaultdict(list)

for a, b in zip(a, b):
    c[a].append(b)

d = {k: v if len(v) > 1 else v[0] for k, v in c.items()}
print(c)
print(d)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': [1, 6], 'B': [2, 3], 'C': [4], 'D': [5]})
{'A': [1, 6], 'B': [2, 3], 'C': 4, 'D': 5}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to use append. Fixed the question.

Comment: ah ok so running your latest code you have even single items for C and D also in lists. Do you want single items to be stored not in lists. or its ok to store them in lists.

Comment: It is ok to have them as the only item in the list. Later on they are going to get processed and the list is going to grow. Again, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: No probs i commented in your question to say based on the update i think what your doing is probably already the cleanest way and that defaultdict is only handy when you dont know all the keys, but in this case you know all the keys in advance to making a dict comp using lists and set of keys is clean and efficient